# Creating Minikube Containers and Communication Between Containers

Tags: containers, minikube

I am working on a project using technologies I've never worked with before and I was wondering if you guys could help me out.

I am currently working on a project to monitor network traffic using Zeek. The end product is a dashboard which will show alerts based off of Zeek notifications. The requirements state that this needs to be done in Kubernetes, so I will be using Minikube to host the cluster.

Within this cluster, I have a singular pod which should contain multiple containers. Each container should contain one tool. Starting with the first container, we need Zeek which will monitor the network traffic and produce logs. In another container, we will have MariaDB; a database where we will store the log data from Zeek. In another container, we will need to hold the dashboard files (.dart files). For the dashboard, we will be using Flutter.

That should be 3 separate containers within our singular pod. If we wanted to get log data from Zeek to MariaDB and the container for our dashboard, what would be the best way to go about this?

So far, I have searched and found potential solutions for communication between containers..

- Using localhost:ports
- Using a shared volume (persistent volume)

Any links/resources I can see for example would be helpful please.

#### Cluster information:

Kubernetes version:
Host OS: Linux, Ubuntu 22.04

#### yaml file:

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: zeek-mariadb-pod
spec:
volumes: # Testing possible shared volume option

- name: shared-data
  persistentVolumeClaim:
  claimName: shared-data-pvc

containers:

- name: zeek-container
  image: testzeek # Custom zeek image
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  volumeMounts:

  - name: shared-data
    mountPath: /zeek-logs
- name: mariadb-container
  image: mariadb
  env:

  - name: ROOT_PASSWORD
    value: mypassword
  - name: DATABASE
    value: /zeek_logs
    volumeMounts:
  - name: shared-data
    mountPath: /zeek-logs

Tried creating a shared volume in the yaml file, researched a bit on localhost:ports, haven't been able to concretely confirm shared volume creation, haven't figured out communication using localhost ports

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes, there is a descriptor called “[Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)” to expose a pod with an unique IP address and a DNS to be accessible by the other pods within a kubernetes cluster.

In your case, let's say you have the pod called *shared-data*, which has port 8080 listening by one of containers.
Then this pod can be exposed as a service.

```
kubectl expose pod shared-data --target-port=8080 --name=shared-data-service -n your_namespace.
```

Other pods within the Kubernetes now should be able access the service via the endpoint,

```
http://shared-data-service.your_namespace.svc.cluster.local:8080
```

Instead, kubectl command above, you can have the service descriptor in a yaml as the following (also, allow multiple ports to expose)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: shared-data-service
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: shared-data
  ports:
    - name: zeek
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: mariadb
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
```